# Sure vs almost sure convergence for a simple random variable

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

I thought I totally got it until I faced a simple problem and realized I'm getting a contradiction. For a sequence of independent simple rv defined on Lebesgue measure $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ on $[0,1]$:
$$
X_n (\omega) = \bigg\{
\begin{array}{;r}
1 & \text{if } \omega \in (0, \frac{1}{n})\\
0& otherwise
\end{array}
$$
the limit is $X(\omega)=0 \ \forall \ \omega \  \in \  \Omega$. If I fix $\omega$, then $|X_{n \geq \frac{1}{\omega}} - X(\omega)|=0$, and this is true $\forall \ \Omega$, so $\lim_n X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \ \forall \ \Omega.$, i.e. sure convergence. At the same time, to get convergence almost surely, I find
$$
\mu(\{\omega:|X_n(\omega) \neq X(\omega)|\}) = \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow\sum_n\mu(X_n (\omega) \neq X(\omega)) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n} \to \infty
$$
Therefore, $X_n (\omega) \not\to X(\omega)$ a.s., because it is $=1$ i.o. w.p. $1$ (it's easy to see it converges in probability because $\frac{1}{n} \to_n  0$).

So I'd be grateful if someone could point out the flaw in my my logic.

Comment: @Exodd but $\mu(0)=0$?

Comment: your rv are not independent as you claim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is irrelevant:
$$
\mu(\{\omega:|X_n(\omega) \neq X(\omega)|\}) = \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow\sum_n\mu(X_n (\omega) \neq X(\omega)) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n} \to \infty
$$
From this you cannot conclude $X_n(\omega) \ne X(\omega)\text{ i.o.}$.

Perhaps you are trying to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma, but that would require that the events $\{X_n (\omega) \neq X(\omega)\}$ are independent.

Comment: Why can't I conclude this? $P(|X_n|>0 i.o.) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n} \to \infty$, so $P(X_n \neq X i.o.)=1$

Comment: I still don't get why/if it converges pointwise, but not a.s.

Comment: @Alex because you are using Borel-Cantelli, that requires indepent rv. But $X_n$ are not independent

Comment: Yeah I see that now, $P(X_n \cap X_{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n+1} \neq P(X_n)(P(X_{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{n+1}$, so Borel-Cantelli can't be applied

Comment: So if my logic for pointwise convergence is correct, it must extend to all other types of convergence by definition then, right?

Comment: pointwise convergence implies almost sure convergence and convergence in probability. There are other types of convergence (uniform, $L^p$, etc.) that are not implied by pointwise convergence though @Alex

Comment: Got it thanks. The rest of the proof is correct though, because convergence is true $\forall \ \Omega$?